# Why some global variables' size is zero in symbol table?

Tags: c

Here is code:

wubing@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ readelf -s testVar1.o

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS testVar1.cc
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     **8: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 uninit1
     9: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 uninit2
    10: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 uninit3
    11: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 unitit4**
    12: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
```

wubing@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ cat testVar1.cc

```
int uninit1;
int uninit2;
int uninit3=3;
int unitit4=4;
int main()
{
  ;
}
```

Comment: Well, are you actually using the variables in your program? Otherwise they shouldn't get allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why some global variables' size is zero in symbol table?

Look, the marked variables don't have zero, but `4` in the `Size` column, just `uninit1` and `uninit3` have zero in the `Value` column, which is the segment address offset. And if you're about to ask why both have the same offset: They're in different segments (`Ndx` `3` and `2`, probably BSS and DATA).